# making it impossible to change a secure key passphrase

Tags: ssh, encryption

According to this:

[How do I change my private key passphrase?](https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase)

it is possible to change your private RSA/DSA key passphrase any time. Is there a way to generate a key with a passphrase that is set once and can not be altered?

Comment: If you wanted to have an unchangeable private key,  then you would probably need to consider looking at hardware based keys.  IE a private key exists on a  physical token.

Answer (score 1):

No, and the question doesn't make sense either. There is no reason for this. A private key is just that.

Comment: It certainly does make sense in some contexts - for example, in the context of ensuring a certain security posture - such as a private key with a mandated passphrase. That makes the mere theft of that private key of little advantage to the bad guy as he is still one authentication factor short of success.

Comment: No, you don't "mandate" a passphrase. That's something that stays in your head and is never shared with anyone. Your proposal is a frightening loss of security.

Comment: @BorisEpstein I wouldn't consider the password on a private key a different factor from the private key itself. I understand that one issue with a user changing their own private key password is they may make it insecure (mom's birthday) or remove it entirely, but perhaps a better solution would be adding a password factor to the login system itself that /can/ be regulated, since this simply isn't possible or advisable for a private key.